# Fetching 2 or more objects with PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm using php and pdo in my project. In this project, i have a lot of selects with join and returns of the diferents table.

When return is only from 1 table, i'm using PDO::FETCH_CLASS to population my object with return of DB, (All the atributes of classes have the same name of columns of DB) my problem is population 2 or more objects with the same query.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: the code is not import in this case, because i need e generic solution to fetching multiples objects, same the PDO::FETCH_CLASS, but i cant passing 2 or more objects to this static function of pdo. In my searchs i dont see nothing of PDO to resolve this problem, only uses ORM's

Comment: so you expect someone to write a generic solution for you. hmm never knew Stack overflow was a free coding writing service. Maybe i didn't get the memo

Comment: That's an interesting problem but I'd suggest you to re-ask and re-phrase your question, as at the moment it sounds as though there is some obvious functionality lacking in PDO. Of course it is not the case and PDO is not supposed to return you multiple objects, so you have to write such a code by hand. Asking for the generic solution, without blaming PDO for not returning you multiple objects, would make a legitimate question, IMO

Answer (score -1):

If what you're talking about is generating two classes from one database row, then using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` or `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` isn't going to help because the cursor moves on to the next rowset after `fetch()` is called. Rewinding the PDO result set is database-dependant, so your DB may not support that.

Your alternative is to use `PDOStatement::fetchAll` then during iteration over that nested array set, make decisions per row as to whether you hydrate one or two objects. You'll likely need a constructor or public setters in order to do that.